# Use angular-input-mask twice time followed

Tags: angularjs

In this code:

```
<div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">CEP Origem: </span>
        <input type="text" id="origem" ng-model="cep" ui-br-cep-mask>
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">CEP Destino: </span>
        <input type="text" id="destino" ng-model="cep" ui-br-cep-mask>
    </label>
</div>
```

When I completed any one of the two the other have the same value, how can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both have the same model, provide different model for each input will solve this issue. You can also use  object and bind the keys.

```
<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">CEP Origem: </span>
    <input type="text" id="origem" ng-model="cep.origem" ui-br-cep-mask>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">CEP Destino: </span>
    <input type="text" id="destino" ng-model="cep.destino" ui-br-cep-mask>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because both of your inputs are using the same `ng-model`. Simply set a different one should help you

Answer (score 0):

[**`ng-model`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) defines the variable that will be edited by your input.

So, if your inputs have the **same** `ng-model`, it will edit the **same** variable.

---

Here you just have to change the ng-model of your second input:

```
<input type="text" id="origem" ng-model="cep1" ui-br-cep-mask>
<input type="text" id="destino" ng-model="cep2" ui-br-cep-mask>
```